# Ember Data rootState.error when editing field after commit

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember.TextField bound to the title field in my Document model. I'm using the RESTAdapter and Ember 1.0.0-pre4.

Model and controllers

```
App.Document = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});

App.DocumentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  save: function() {
    var doc = this.controllerFor('document'),
    model = doc.get('model');

    doc.store.commit();
  }
]);
```

document.handlebars template

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="title"}}
```

After calling the `save` method on my controller it will successfully save the `title` to the backend and will no longer be considered `isDirty`.

However if I input any data into the TextField after a `save` Ember Data throws me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `willSetProperty`
on <App.Document:ember262:1> while in state rootState.error.
Called with
{reference: [object Object], store: <App.Store:ember268>, name: title}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging it turns out that the PUT 204 success code returned by Rails is not enough for Ember to accept the changes made.

Here's what I did:

```
# format.json { head :no_content } # Rails default behavior
format.json { render json: @post } # Ember needs some data in return / 200 success code
```